# python pandas read dataframe and do not include index

Tags: python, pandas

very simple question

I am reading an excel sheet with python and I want to print the results without the automatic index pandas adds

```
import pandas as pd

x=pd.read_excel(r'2_56_01.276295.xlsx',index_col=None)
print x[:3]
```

this prints the 1st 3 rows

```
   blahblah           Street Borough
0        55         W 192 ST   Bronx
1      2514  EAST TREMONT AV   Bronx
2       877     INTERVALE AV   Bronx
```

but I do not want the index

Comment: Question: why dont you want the index?

Comment: because I am creating a JSON array to display on a webpage and its just screwing it up

Comment: are you using `df.to_json()` if so i think you can use `orient=r` : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: @anky_91 did not know about this, looks super useful but the JSON is parsed in a unique way. but this may be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print x.to_string(index=False)
```

should do the trick